# Show spinner while loading image in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

how can i show spinner while i'm loading images in my angular?
**i don't want my image load piece by piece**

i tried this way but it didn't work out:

```
imageLoader = false;  loading: boolean = true
    
    onLoad() {
        this.loading = false;
    }

    <img *ngIf="loading" src="/assets/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
    <img [hidden]="loading" (load)="onLoad()" src="{{ source }}" />
```

Comment: Where did you get your image source via API call or from asset directory?

Comment: it comes from api

Comment: Then do your logic before getting a response and after getting a response.
For example:
**this.loading = true;
this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      
      this.source = data.src;
      this.loading = false;
    });**

Comment: ok thanks i will try it